# How do I start a background thread with a request in the Play! framework?

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

I've been looking into the Play! framework and I'm interested in converting one of my projects over to it. However, this project requires that long-running threads be spawned upon a user action, but the result of the thread is not returned to the user via a normal request-response method. Instead, the user is redirected to a page which monitors the threads they have started.

So, I'm wondering how I can create a user action that creates a thread whenever a user POSTs to /start, but the thread automatically goes into the "background" and the user receives a response such as "ok" or even a redirect, rather than the output of the thread.

I also want some degree of control over the threads; in other words, I don't just want to create a thread and leave it to run. I want to have some kind of global reference point so that a user can stop a thread once it has been started (e.g. by visiting /stop).

Comment: Have you looked at Akka? I thought it was a first class citizen of play 2.

Comment: I think Akka only supports scheduled Jobs. I don't require those; I need proper Threads which can do things whilst the user interacts with the application.

Comment: Akka is based on the Actor/message model. I would think you can get these kick started by programmatically. I would stay away from your own threads if you want to avoid concurrency issues, that is exactely what Akka is made for and is great at it from what I understand!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Play provides special Job which can be run in background periodically or on application startup, but I don't think it is suitable for you.

In your case, you can simply spawn new `Thread` or submit new task to `Executor`, using Java API and return response to user. For stopping `Thread` you can use standard approach with loop and interrupted flag. Nothing special from play framework here, just regular java api.

Comment: I'm not sure that works. I set up a simple Thread that waited for 10 seconds, started it and then returned an ok() to the page. However, when I ran the app, the request would still appear to wait for 10 seconds before it returned the ok().

How would I use the Executor in play?

Comment: What method have you used for starting thread run or start ? When new request arrives spawn new Thread with start method and return response to user. There is nothing special with Play. You can try it with console Java application and main method

Comment: Ah, I think I was running it with run(). It works now with start(). How about the second part of my question though; where would I have to store a reference to the Thread object in order to control it between requests?

Comment: It's slightly more complicated. In few words: after starting your Thread, usually it will be running in infinite while (flag) loop. Whenever user submit abother POST request, you have to set this flag to false. Please, refer to thread/task cancellation in Java. Also you have to store somewhere references between users and their Thread. To simplify it, it can be Map where keys are user's login and values of map are Thread itself or another class which wraps your Thread

Comment: Ok, but where should the Map be located? In Application.java or somewhere else?

Comment: Jobs are for Play 1.0, check out Actors and Akka in the documentation for 2.0

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't spawn new `Thread` instances but use `Actor` instances instead. They're a more simple and robust model for doing non-blocking tasks in the background.

Refer to the [Play](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/ScalaAkka) and [Akka](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.2/intro/getting-started-first-scala.html) documentation for details.